# Trying to query for email addresses with 'Open' status within Q1 and has annual value of specific amount

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, Accounts and Opportunities. Accounts table has columns `account_name`, `account_id`, and `account_email_addresses`. Opportunities has `opp_id, account_id, opp_stage, created_date, close_date, and mrr (mrr=monthly recurring revenue)`

I am wanting to query for a list of the account email addresses in 'Open' status (opp_stage), worth more than `$10,000` in ANNUAL recurring revenue (I am thinking `WHERE 'mrr' * 12 >= 10,000`), and then lastly is within Q1 (I am thinking `WHERE close_date BETWEEN '1/1/2023' AND '3/31/2023`'

Can you critique my syntax and let me know if I have done anything wrong? I am particularly unsure about the WHERE NOT (the opp stage can be anything other than Closed Won or Closed Lost) and the MRR statements.

```
Select account_email_address, account_id
FROM Accounts
Right Join Opportunities
  ON accounts.account_id=opportunities.account_id
WHERE NOT opp_stage 'Closed Won' OR 'Closed Lost'
  AND close_date BETWEEN '1/1/2023' AND '3/31/2023'
  AND 'mrr' * 12 >= 10,000;
```

Comment: Most people find `main table LEFT JOIN optional data` much easier to get than `optional data RIGHT JOIN main table`.

Comment: `AND` goes before `OR`. Do you really want `WHERE (NOT opp_stage 'Closed Won') OR ('Closed Lost' AND close_date BETWEEN '1/1/2023' AND '3/31/2023' AND 'mrr' * 12 >= 10,000)`? I'd guess you mean `WHERE opp_stage NOT IN ('Closed Won', 'Closed Lost') AND ...`

Comment: It's good programming practice to _qualify_ all columns, like accounts.account_id instead of just opp_stage.

Comment: Please share more details, like the table structure, sample input data, the expected output according to that sample data, and your attempts to resolve the problem

Answer (score 0):

The 'not' predicate operations have parser execution precedence. In your version of the condition, what you expect to see will not work. You need to write like this:

```
Select account_email_address, account_id
FROM Accounts
left Join Opportunities
  ON accounts.account_id=opportunities.account_id
WHERE (opp_stage NOT in ('Closed Won','Closed Lost'))
  AND close_date BETWEEN '1/1/2023' AND '3/31/2023'
  AND 'mrr' * 12 >= 10,000;
```